# How to count number of a key in a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I have a json dataset of dict (and list?). Dataset looks like this:

```
{
    "address": "8.8.8.8",
    "lookup_results": {
        "start_time": "2012-03-11T09:30:37.094Z",
        "detected_by": 1,
        "sources": [
            {
                "provider": "name_prov_1",
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "provider": "name_prov_2",
                "status": 0
            },
            {
                "provider": "name_prov_3",
                "status": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to count the number of providers in ["lookup_results"]["sources"], because the number can change over the time. 
My solution gives back "TypeError list indices must be integers not str". 
Can someone help me with this? 
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
dictionary = {
    "address": "8.8.8.8",
    "lookup_results": {
        "start_time": "2012-03-11T09:30:37.094Z",
        "detected_by": 1,
        "sources": [
            {
                "provider": "name_prov_1",
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "provider": "name_prov_2",
                "status": 0
            },
            {
                "provider": "name_prov_3",
                "status": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```
len(dictionary['lookup_results']["sources"])
```

```
3
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for help, a way too easy...I don't understand what i was trying.